# when creating a PHP static function which is right putting the static first or second

Tags: php

```
public static function(){
}
```

or

```
static public function(){
}
```

I have seen both ways and both seem to work.
Does it matter? 
Is there a difference?

Comment: It doesn't matter from a technical perspective, but some style guides have opinions, e.g. see [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/): "`static` MUST be declared after the visibility."

Comment: There isn't a difference, however as @Chris mentioned, there are multiple different coding standards.  In many companies too there will be some kind of BDP which may (probably should) set out coding standards for any languages they use which will standardise things like this across the business.

Comment: @JonTaylor, I guess that should be "BPD" for "best-practices document"?

Comment: @Chris Business Development Practises , probably called different things in different companies :) Either way though the point still stands whatever it's called.

Answer (score 5):

> **[PHP Manual> Language Reference> Classes and Objects> Static Keyword](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)**
>
> **Example #1 Static method example**
>
> ```
> <?php
> class Foo {
>     public static function aStaticMethod() {
>         // ...
>     }
> }
> ```

---

> **[PHP Manual> Language Reference> Classes and Objects> Visibility](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)**
>
> The visibility of a property or method can be defined **by prefixing the declaration** with the keywords `public`, `protected` or `private`.

So even if it's allowed, the classic way is **`public static`**